# Show Custom Fields under "Add to Cart" button

Tags: wordpress, function, field, custom-fields

I have using this function code to make new Custom Text Area, but have issue to show it in product page.

```
// Custom Field Product
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 
'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 
'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );

function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

  global $woocommerce, $post;

  echo '<div class="options_group">';

  woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( 
    array( 
    'id'          => '_textarea', 
    'label'       => __( 'Custom Text:', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'placeholder' => '', 
    'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ) 
)
);

echo '</div>';

}

// Save Changes to DB

function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){
 // Textarea
$woocommerce_textarea = $_POST['_textarea'];
if( !empty( $woocommerce_textarea ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_textarea', esc_html( $woocommerce_textarea 
) );
}

// Show data to product
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 
'custom_content_after_addtocart_button', 100 );
function custom_content_after_addtocart_button() {
// custom content.
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_textarea', true );
}
```

Looks like when press save, its storing data in DB, but its not showing in single product page. Can someone to tell me where is issue in this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the following `function`, `$post` is not defined. (The code was indented for clarity.)

```
// Show data to product
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 
'custom_content_after_addtocart_button', 100 );
function custom_content_after_addtocart_button() {
    // custom content.
    echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_textarea', true );
}
```

So, a simple fix would be to add `global $post;` to the `function`:

```
// Show data to product
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 
'custom_content_after_addtocart_button', 100 );
function custom_content_after_addtocart_button() {
    global $post;

    // custom content.
    if ( $post ) {
        echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_textarea', true );
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the global `$product` object:

```
// Show data to product
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 
'custom_content_after_addtocart_button', 100 );
function custom_content_after_addtocart_button() {
    global $product;

    // custom content.
    if ( $product ) {
        echo get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_textarea', true );
    }
}
```